# Apache http auth loop, Location and .htaccess together

Tags: apache, .htaccess, loops, authentication, location

I have an Apache auth loop. In my vhost config file, I have a Location directive to password protect a specific URL:

```
    <Location /academics/faculty-development>
            AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd2
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Who's a good boy?"
            Require valid-user
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>
```

However, I also have an .htaccess in our web root that protects the entire site.

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected"
Require valid-user
```

Both logins work and authenticate, but when you log in with one, the other pops up. Logging in to that one makes the other come back.

How do I get my .htaccess to ignore authorization for that specific URL?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing the auth contents in an htaccess file at the `/academics/faculty-development` location? According to the documentation, stuff like `AuthType` isn't supposed to be put in a `<Location>` container.

According to the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#authtype), you can only place this stuff in either a `<Directory>` container or in an htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same realm in the AuthName directive for both authentications (so either change "Who's a good boy?" to "Protected" or vice-versa), so that the browser will reuse the same credentials and will not ask for the password again.